# How to force to refresh a web page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a web server.

BEFORE: There was a website. "domain.com/" redirected to "domain.com/index.html" (logic) and this page redirected to "domain.com/en/index.html" with the tag :
"*meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=en/index.html"*"

NOW: There is a Wordpress (I installed it), without index.html but an index.php.

THE PROBLEM: When I want to access to "domain.com", I am redirected to domain.com/en/index.html.

I know it is a cache problem but how to disabled this cache. Redirection ?

I have found a solution about the htaccess  (add Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ) but it doesn't work.

Below the network analyzer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is actually a `DirectoryIndex` issue, not a cache one.

If you look at [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectoryIndex), you see that this directive takes a list of indexes which Apache attempts to locate in order. Therefor, you can force priority for `index.php` by moving it to the front of the list

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I work with disabled cache, the website display the wordpress (-> index.php). DirectoryIndex is a good idea but I haven't access the apache config ...  I tried to add it in the .htaccess but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect is a 301, then  you need to use "Forget about this site" because 301 is a permanent redirect and will be saved in browser cache. A simple page reload will not refresh the cache.

I've often stumble upon this scenario:

`foo.com` redirects using `301` to `bar.com`, when you first visit `foo.com`, the browser will remember that redirect and the next time you visit `foo.com`, the browser will not even connect to `foo.com`, but instead connect directly to `bar.com`.

@edit:
It seems to be a 302 redirect.
Just edit `yourwebsite.com/index.html` and change from `meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=en/index.html` to `meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=en/index.php`. Basically, change the extension from .html to .php in the refresh meta.

Comment: Oh no, it is not a 301, just a page with this tag : "meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=en/index.html"

Comment: Yeah, it is that ;) But I think I can disabled that, because html is in the user browser cache :/